# Changing font-familiy in email template

Tags: html, css, email

I want to change the `font-family` in my e-mail template, but it doesn't change font. Here is my code.

```
<style>
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
</style>

<p style="font-family:Open Sans;">forgot your passwrod?</p>
```

How can I solve this problem?

p.s. I have tested this in gmail.

Comment: It's strongly advised to use only standard fonts in email, otherwhise many mailboxes will replace them with a defaut font.

Answer (score 1):

When you are stating a font-family that has a space inside it, the name needs to be in quotes. Also, I'd recommend you place a fallback, just in case it doesn't load.

```
<p style="font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif;">forgot your password?</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add google font in email template but you can specify font in inline css which load font from local system

```
<table style="font-family:Open Sans;">
  <tr>
    <td><p>forgot your passwrod?</p></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note: internal & external style doesn't support email template.